# Custom Framework using javascript using input parameters of id of content div?

Tags: javascript, ajax, frameworks

I am creating a mini website that has one HTML snippet file to hold just the content that's desired for each internal link in the navigation bar. Each file shall contain the content that shall be inserted into the content placeholder of the template file (index.html).

*I have to create a framework JS file with a  "make framework" function that has an input parameter which is id of a content div that will be controlled by the framework.
The "make framework" function shall return an object that has a public method that accepts the name of an HTML snippet file and places the content of the snippet file into the content div.
The "make framework" function shall have a private ajax calling function that accepts callback functions as input parameters.*

I do not get how to start my framework or how to do it. I have already created my mini website and each button click shows the content. I know that later on I would have to make it so that those button clicks will be moved inside my navigation bar as links instead of buttons.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS Framework</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="title">
                <img src="pics/logo.png" width="160" height="39" alt="">
            </div>

            <div id="navLink">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="02_advLayout/index.html">avdLayout</a>
                <a href="05_js_fw/index.html">JS Framework</a>
                <a href="labs.html">Labs</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <button onclick="sendRequest('aboutUs.html')">cars</button> 
        &nbsp;
        <button onclick="sendRequest('aboutCoffee.html')">people</button>

        <div id="bodyContent">
            Content Area
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            Web footer
        </div>

        <script>

            // Make a global XMLHttpRequest Object
            var httpReq;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();  //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                httpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");    //For IE 5+
            } else {
                alert('ajax not supported');
            }

            function sendRequest(url) {
                httpReq.open("GET", url);
                httpReq.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
                httpReq.send(null);
            }

            function handleResponse() {
                if (httpReq.readyState === 4 && httpReq.status === 200) {
                    var response = httpReq.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("bodyContent").innerHTML = response;
                }
            }

            sendRequest('aboutUs.html');

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

AJAX file:

```
function ajaxCall(url, successFn, errorFn) {

    // variable/property that's private to fn ajaxCall
    var httpReq;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();  //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        httpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");         //For IE 5+
    } else {
        alert('ajax not supported');
    }

    // private function
    function sendRequest() {
        //alert ('sending request');
        httpReq.open("GET", url);
        httpReq.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
        httpReq.send(null);
    }

    // another private function
    function handleResponse() {
        //alert('handling response');
        if (httpReq.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpReq.status === 200) {

                var response = httpReq.responseText;
                //alert ("response text is " + response);

                // wrap the json in parentheses to avoid tripping over javascript ambiguity...
                response = "(" + response + ")";
                var jsonObj = eval(response);
                successFn(jsonObj); // we are passing BACK jsonObj to the HTML page
            } else {
                errorFn(httpReq);  // we are passing BACK the whole httpReq object to the 
                                   // HTML page, they can extract error codes etc from there.
            }
        }
    } // handleResponse

    sendRequest();
} // ajaxCall
```

html snippet files:

[click here](https://gist.github.com/76342ck/2fef8a4c2f14991cece43ded25799a15)

See the Pen [jZKWPo](https://codepen.io/76342ck/pen/jZKWPo/) by Sofia ([@76342ck](https://codepen.io/76342ck)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Can you recreate your website in the code snippet here or on Codepen or somewhere? Will make it easier to suggest edits.

Comment: @Aydin4ik I added what I could in CodePen

Comment: Is this what you are after? https://codepen.io/aydin4ik/project/editor/XYrypy

Comment: @Aydin4ik umm I only see the same thing I posted. I need to create a framework.js file that calls the content id and passes it through. so instead of using the AJAX code in the index.html file, it will have it's own framework file with the AJAX code in a separate file. The problem I am having is in the italicized paragraph.

Comment: https://codepen.io/76342ck/project/editor/AxbGRM#0

Comment: How about this: https://codepen.io/aydin4ik/project/editor/XqBOqr

Comment: @Aydin4ik yes! thank you!

Comment: Added it as an answer, if you accept it we can consider this question as closed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that takes ID of the target object and url of the HTML snippet, then calls the url and appends the response to the target object:

```
function loadUrl(container,url) {
    var httpReq;
    var output;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();  //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        httpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");         //For IE 5+
    } else {
        alert('ajax not supported');
    }

    function sendRequest(url) {
        httpReq.open("GET", url);
        httpReq.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
        httpReq.send(null);        
    }

    function handleResponse() {
        if (httpReq.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpReq.status === 200) {
              var response = httpReq.responseText;
                output = response; // Result of a successful response
            } else {
                output = httpReq.response;  // Result of a failed response
            }
          document.getElementById(container).innerHTML = output; // Append the response to the designated container
        }
    } 
    // Run the script
    sendRequest(url);
}
```

Then you can use this function wherever you need to retrieve a snippet for your index.html, for example:

```
loadUrl('contentId','aboutUs.html');
```

You can see a working example here: https://codepen.io/aydin4ik/project/editor/XqBOqr